# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError exception while creating EpcDocument object from FesApi with in teiid jboss translator development

Tags: java, dll, unsatisfiedlinkerror, teiid, target-link-libraries

I am getting this exception while try to read epc file in EpcDocument with in Teiid Translator deployed in Jboss server
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:com.f2i.energisticsStandardsApi.fesapiJNI.new_common_EpcDocument(Ljava/lang/String;)J at com.f2i.energisticsStandardsApi.fesapiJNI.new_common_EpcDocument(Native Method)
           at com.f2i.energisticsStandardsApi.common.EpcDocument.(EpcDocument.java:42)

```
Static {
      try {
           //Also tried this way
           // System.load("D:\\fesapiEnv\\build\\fesapi\\install\\lib\\FesapiCpp.1.2.0.0.dll");
            System.loadLibrary("FesapiCpp.1.2.0.0");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            System.out.println("UnsatisfiedLinkError : " + e.toString());
        }
      }
  public static void serializeEPC(String filePathwithName) {
        // This class allows an access to a memory package representing an EPC document.
        EpcDocument pck = new EpcDocument(filePathwithName);
        // This abstract class acts as a buffer between the RESQML (business) classes
        // and the persisted data.
        DataObjectRepository repo = new DataObjectRepository();
}
```

I have also added environment path variable for DLL files(FesapiCpp.1.2.0.0.dll) loading of in bat file of Jboss as below
set PATH=%jBOSS_HOME%\modules\system\layers\base\com\f2i\energisticsStandardsApi\main\lib;%PATH%

The  fesApi jar that i am using i get compiled form the below link

### https://github.com/F2I-Consulting/fesapi

The Strange thing happening is that when i run standalone programme it runs successfully but with in Jboss environment it gives above exception.

Answer (score 0):

Actually energisticsStandardsApi.jar was loaded as independent module in wildfly server while i was consuming it in separate module (Teiid Translator for RESQML).The above mentioned static block of code was in Translator module where i was loading DLL files while FesapiCpp.1.2.0.0.dll was being consumed by energisticsStandardsApi module, so this producing java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError exception while creating EpcDocument object.